# How to set outbound property on a Mule message

Tags: mule

It looks to me that `<set-property>` only sets inbound properties (right?). How can I set `outbound property`, aiming to carry it across transport barriers and then use `<copy-properties>` to copy it to outbound from inbound.

I don't want to set session variables are lost amid flows by outbound endpoints

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I was doing `<set-property>` but accessing it like `#[propertyName]` instead of `#[message.outboundProperties.propertyName]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set-property` adds outbound message properties. If you want to check all message properties use a `logger` component or you can use Mule 3.4.0 (Beta) that comes with a visual flow debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Set-variable sets the properties in the INVOCATION scope.

Use message properties transformer  to add variables in different scopes.

Comment: The OP is using `set-property` not `set-variable`.